# How to write differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a scenario that I am stuck on involving writing a differential equation that models the fish population. I don't believe I am doing it right. Can someone please help?

Scenario: A lake with a fixed carrying capacity contains a certain fish population. The fish population in the lake has a growth rate that is proportional to its size when the population is very small relative to the carrying capacity. However, when the fish population exceeds the carrying capacity, the growth rate is negative.

Can someone give me an example of how to set it up please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(t)$ denote the fish population as a function of time.

To satisfy your conditions, we can write: $\frac{dF}{dt} = \kappa F(1-\frac{F}{C})$

Where $C$ is the carrying capacity, $\kappa$ is a positive constant.

Note when $F$ is small (relative to $C$), the term $\frac{F}{C}$ is relatively small, so $(1-\frac{F}{C})$ is close to $1$, and thus $\frac{dF}{dt}$ is close to $\kappa F$ (so proportional to $F$).

When $F > C, \frac{F}{C} > 1$ and so $(1- \frac{F}{C})$ is negative, and so $\frac{dF}{dt}$ will be negative.

For more information on this look up "logistic differential equation."